# Windows 7 running slowly despite having lots CPU and memory free

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance, cpu

This is my computer spec:

```
Intel i7 2500k @ 3.4ghz
Win7 64bit
16gb of ram
Radeon HD 6800
```

My computer is starting to run progressively slower; for example, when switching between programs i.e. Excel to Word, there tends to be quite a bit of lag 2/3 seconds before the selected program loads up. The problem of general slowness is not constant and can vary in degrees from more or less unusable to something fairly OK

Actions taken so far:

```
Ran Windows memory checker and all seems fine
Checked the disk
Checked to make sure
Ran CCleaner
Performed system restore from a month ago!
Checked CPU temps
Checked all CPUs haven't been disabled
```

I have run the resource monitor but to be truthful I'm not sure what I'm looking at. The CPU and memory seem to be running at low levels but unsure about the disk.

Comment: check power plan. install hwinfo64 and report that your cpu is not underclocked

Comment: it could be your hard disk dying. when your pc is reading from hard drive and it takes long, windows doesnt skip anything, it just waits until hard drive sends the data. Are you using an SSD or not

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan - I've installed hwinfo64, not really sure how I generate a report to see if my cpu is underclocked.

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan - I've looked at the benchmarks within hwinfo64 and it shows my my disk read burst is fairly low done compared to everything which is fairly near the top - no I dont use a SSD. What is the best way to improve this ? I do use Truecrypt also

Comment: buy an SSD and use it as your OS drive. Keep all your data on a normal HDD

Comment: are you encrypting your OS drive? if thats the case, dont do it. Your problem is most likely to be caused by encryption or failing hard disk drive

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan yes using encryption on the OS drive. I'm guessing that it maybe my hard-drive then rather than anything else. Anyway of checking if it is the hard-drive. Can you use a SSD with TC and still have full encryption ?

Comment: yes it would work but I dont recommend it. you should only encrypt files other than program files anyway

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert, but I say is via my hands on experience. This is not a fix for the problem, but can be helpful in this issue or many others.  So don't be pissed i say the following :)

I suggest checking a few other things.  Many run cleaners,but they don't get everything. We all know when we install, very sneaky non malware programs piggyback on legit programs, and very often run hidden in the background. Then they become hard to track.  Then the hidden non maleware coupled with legit programs, result in compatibility issues and can cause such havoc. Of the auto programs of the so called anti virus or best Maleware cleaner, run to  prevent you from deleting them. Ironically the anti  malware  you did not install or tried to uninstall becomes a pup, or offers the problem of deletion, only to rebuild and return.

When we uninstall, many programs leave a tiny bit of code behind, and over time rebuild a connection to the original server, and you are tracked. Also, to uninstall, does not mean you get all cleaned out. I periodically clean, then manually go through hidden system folders. It is amazing to find things you had no idea you are running in the background, sucking your processing power.  My setup is Win 7. 3.5 Gigahertz six core processor, 16 Gig DDR ram etc.  Download is 25 Mbps, upload is the same. My system is not even taxed, yet buffers movies sometimes

I'd check what is running, via Task Manager, Apps, and Services.  When you are not familiar with, do a Internet search.  You will others with specific questions about some obscure name with no legit server name. i.e. 'IMFTips.' what is it?  When I see it, I do the search.  Many times i found things that only slow me down.

Check Start up items, and always what runs in background.  If you have a difficult one to remove, startup in 'Safe Mode,' with networking.  That loads only core drivers and no boutique programs.  FYI, the reason some malware masquerading as legit, then they won't totally uninstall, is if any part runs, it is not subject for removal.  IN SAFE MODE, they are not loaded and the eliminating is easy. So, I am  not giving advice to a fix it quick, but he he, many people suffer as I did, and a really clean machine will be a factor for sauccess, and to maintain y our machine, one  much learn these basics.

I hope I did not offend anyone. I stand on this.  I don't care how hot your processor is or what model you machine is. VERY often a sneaky bit of code NOT malware, but not known to be running or or incompatible with what you have, will create a myriad of issues.

Best...